# How to add a printable or non-printable bitmap stamp to a PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, digital-signature

I would like to add a bitmap stamp to a PDF file, that would be either printable or non-printable depending on the actual Acrobat Reader print settings.

I.e. when user selects in AR Print dialog combo box the option "Document" - then it would not be printed, but when "Document and stamps" is selected then the bitmap would print.

Right now I can create either printable or non-printable bitmap, but I am unable to create a bitmap that would be **both printable and non-printable depending on users choice**.

Using [PdfStamper](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html).

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you aware that you are creating a signature field, not an actual digital signature? (You claim that you can create a PDF with a digital signature, but that is not what you do in your code snippet!) Also: if you want to add a stamp annotation, why are you adding a widget annotation for a signature field? Why don't you add a stamp annotation if a stamp annotation is what you want? This question is very confusing.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I think the OP thinks that Adobe Reader Stamps coincide with what an iText `PdfStamper` "stamps" onto PDFs. @Vojtěch Please be aware that what Adobe Reader considers stamps is a very special kind of annotation, and a signature visualization is not such a stamp.

Comment: @mkl Aha, OK. And a signature field is not a signature. Right now, it seems that the OP is using a signature field as a stamp, but once the document is signed, the appearance of the signature field will change, so whatever appearance he is defining for his empty signature field is irrelevant: it will no longer be present in the signed document.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for this comments and sorry, I did not want to add too much code so it was perhaps confusing. It seems that adding Stamp annotation instead of just annotation could do the trick, not yet sure how to achieve that.

Comment: Hmm... You are creating an `adbe.pkcs7.sha1` signature. You are aware that these type of signatures are about to be deprecated, aren't you? You should no longer create such signatures. Use `adbe.pkcs7.detached` or `ETSI.CAdES.detached` instead if you want your application to be future-proof.

Comment: I have looked for official information on the subject of `adbe.pkcs7.sha1` from Adobe and found nothing,

Comment: *I have looked for official information on the subject of adbe.pkcs7.sha1 from Adobe and found nothing,* - On this subject you should not look for information from Adobe but instead for information from ISO. The current PDF specification (ISO 32000-1) from 2008 already recommends using **adbe.pkcs7.detached**. The latest ISO 32000-2 draft I have here states "The value *adbe.pkcs7.sha1* has been deprecated. To support backward compatibility, PDF readers should process this value for this key but PDF writers shall not use this value for this key."

Comment: This information seems to be very secret and available only on iText related pages, I have found only: *For maximum interoperability between signature handlers from different vendors, only the SubFilter values adbe.pkcs7.detached and adbe.pkcs7.sha1, as defined in PDF Reference 1.5, should be used.*

Comment: *I have found only: ... should be used.* - "should" implies a lot here:  **SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
   may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
   particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
   carefully weighed before choosing a different course.**

Comment: @mkl It only seems strange to me that I could not find almost any reference on this subject on google. And I am not willing to buy ISO 32000-1:2008 for 198 CHF just to read that.

Comment: First, if some software project is developed without the appropriate specifications, the responsible persons should be aware the software is likely to be deficient. Second, Adobe offers access to a version of the spec merely missing the ISO headings for free.

Comment: Ah, and I mistook your quote, only reading on a smart phone. The relevant sentence is *The format for encoding signature values should be **adbe.pkcs7.detached**. This encoding allows the most
options in terms of algorithm use.* in the section 12.8.3.3 "PKCS#7 Signatures as used in ISO 32000".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating stamp annotations is described in Chapter 7 of [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book), more specifically in the [TimeTableAnnotations3](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=151) example:

```
PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createStamp(stamper.getWriter(),
    rect, "Press only", "NotForPublicRelease");
annotation.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
```

If you look at the print preview, you can see that these annotations don't show up if you print the Document without stamps:

[image]

In C#, the code is very similar to the Java code:

```
 PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateStamp(
     stamper.Writer, rect, "Press only", "NotForPublicRelease"
 );
 annotation.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
```

Note that a PDF viewer should have predefined icons for at least the following names:

- Approved,
- Experimental,
- NotApproved,
- AsIs,
- Expired,
- NotForPublicRelease,
- Confidential,
- Final,
- Sold,
- Departmental,
- ForComment,
- TopSecret,
- Draft,
- ForPublicRelease.

What these icons look like will depend from viewer to viewer.

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting - just is it possible to create custom stamp with itextsharp?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the PDF created by the example, you'll see that the functionality you're asking for also works for line annotations, square annotations, circle annotations,... http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/timetable_tickets.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I will add here the working solution, since it was not really straightforward to figure it out from provided examples. Now there is a custom bitmap stamp annotation within the PDF doc and when clicked, the properties window of digital signature appears.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(this.inputPDF);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
PdfSignatureAppearance sap;
Rectangle stampRect = null;
//Add stamp annotation
if (StampImagePath != null && StampImagePath.Length > 0 && File.Exists(StampImagePath))
{
    Image stampImg = Image.GetInstance(stampImagePath);
    Rectangle location = new Rectangle(stampXpos, stampYpos, stampXpos + stampImg.Width, stampYpos + stampImg.Height);
    PdfAnnotation pdfStamp = PdfAnnotation.CreateStamp(
        stamper.Writer, location, null, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());                    
    stampImg.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
    PdfAppearance app = stamper.GetOverContent(1).CreateAppearance(stampImg.Width, stampImg.Height);
    app.AddImage(stampImg);
    pdfStamp.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, app);
    pdfStamp.SetPage();
    pdfStamp.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
    stamper.AddAnnotation(pdfStamp, 1);
    stampRect = location;
}

....
//After signing the document set visible signature to the annotation rectangle
if (stampRect!=null)
      sap.SetVisibleSignature(stampRect, 1, "SignatureESift");
```