# How to add stamp to PDF in C# using Adobe predefined templates?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, adobe

The task is to add a stamp to existing pdf files. I tried the code in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229629/how-to-add-a-printable-or-non-printable-bitmap-stamp-to-a-pdf) using iTextSharp and the stamp style is like this: [image]

But the I want the stamp looks like what [Adobe provided](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/adding-stamp-pdf.html):[image]

Is there any library provide stamp annotation style like this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't... at least not legally. Adobe distributes that stamp and their stamps in general as PDF files that are in a specific folder of the application and have some special attributes that make them visible in the Acrobat UI. They are considered part of the Acrobat product and are subject to the same licensing restrictions as the executable itself. That's why iText came up with their own version for their sample.

However, you **can** add a stamp annotation that uses the same name as the Adobe Approved stamp "SBApproved" but without an appearance dictionary. In that case, the PDF viewer will generate its own appearance for the stamp (if it can) and the viewer's equivalent of the "SBApproved" stamp will be shown. Unfortunately, it will only look like the Adobe version when opened in an Adobe viewer. Because not all viewers have the ability to generate annotation apppearances, I don't recommend this appraoch. Bruno's answer in the question you referenced explains this a bit further... quoting... emphasis mine.

> **Note that a PDF viewer should have predefined icons for at least the following names:** ***Approved***, Experimental, NotApproved, AsIs, Expired, NotForPublicRelease, Confidential, Final, Sold, Departmental, ForComment, TopSecret, Draft, ForPublicRelease. **What these icons look like will depend from viewer to viewer.**

My advice is to come up with your own design for the stamp and use it.

Comment: Or find a library that will generate the appearances of the stamp annotations just as Adobe Acrobat would. Having the appearance defined in the file should guarantee that the annotation views correctly across PDF viewing applications.